# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. IEnumerator MoveNext()

Tags: c#

I got this error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. on the method bellow. For the method bellow I need 2 parameters, one of this is passed by reference, the one which I need to change while enumerating it. I know that this is the issue why I got this error, my question is how to modify my method? I was looking at all of the same question, but I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

```
public class NeuronConnections : Dictionary<object,object>
    {

        public NeuronConnections() { }

        public ICollection Neurons()
        {
            return base.Keys;
        }

    }

public virtual void UpdateWeights(ref NeuronConnections connections, double delta)
{
    IEnumerator enumerator = null;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            enumerator = connections.Neurons().GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if(enumerator == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                INeuron current = (INeuron)enumerator.Current;
                if (current == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                connections[current] = Convert.ToDouble(connections[current]) + 0.5 * current.Output * delta;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (enumerator is IDisposable)
            {
                ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("UpdateWeights:\n{0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

I use this code on a Windows Phone application.

Comment: Can you loop by index using a `for` statement?

Comment: Why do you write a c# code like java. you have `foreach`, `linq`, `using` etc.

Comment: Why are you passing `connections` by reference at all? What does the `NeuronConnections` type look like?

Comment: Seems like your code can be simplified to something like this **`IEnumerable<Neuron> UpdateWeights(NeuronConnections connections, double delta)
{
 return connections.Neurons().Select(c => Convert.ToDouble(c) + 0.5 * current.Output * delta);
}`**

Comment: I edited my question with the NeuronConnections class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
enumerator = connections.Neurons().GetEnumerator();
```

to

```
enumerator = connections.Neurons().ToList().GetEnumerator();
```

The point being - materialize Your collection. So that You would not be editing the collection you're iterating over

That's what's the compiler is not happy about.. that You modify the collection being iterated.

Comment: I updated my question...the Neurons method contains a collection of keys, and the ICollection does not contain a definition for ToList, ToArray, etc...

Comment: it does if you add `using System.Linq;` ^

Comment: @kenderkin instead of porting a java code line by line, try to use an idiomatic port. That way, your code will be much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much...I forgot to Cast firstly...this is the working code now...enumerator = connections.Neurons().Cast<INeuron>().ToList().GetEnumerator();....thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to modify collections in place. So you should replace your inner try block with this:

```
var neurons = connections.Neurons().ToArray();
for (int i=0; i<neurons.Length; i++) {
    INeuron current = neurons[i];
    if (current == null) continue;
    connections[current] = Convert.ToDouble(connections[current]) + 0.5 * current.Output * delta;
}
```

Another more clean alternative wuld be no to pass initial connections as ref, but to generate a new modified one and return it. I can not give you an example, bacause it may involve a lot of your code which is not shown in example.